# Using $(document).ready(function() to change the text of a label

Tags: javascript, jquery

fI am trying to change a label that says "Copies" in this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.availableLabel.copiedCountLabel').text("Available in Region");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="availableDiv0" class="availableDiv copiesCountSection">
  <span class="availableLabel copiesCountLabel">Copies: </span>
  <span style="display:inline-block;" name="smallSearchingGif" id="copiesCountNumber1040573" class="availableNumber copiesCountNumber">
    2
  </span>
</span>
```

How would I go about changing the text "Copies" to "Available in Region".

Comment: FYI - you can use `$(function() { code... });` as an alias to the `document.ready` function:

Comment: you have a typo when selecting the element: `copiedCountLabel`, when the HTML element have the class called `copiesCountLabel`

Comment: Please don't fix your original code because it makes your question meaningless. If you have something else to add, just edit your question and add more detail.

Comment: Simple typo...Voting to close.

Comment: I did post the typo, but I fixed it. It is correct now and still does not work.

Comment: When you edited your question with the typo fix, it did work. You can see that *[here](http://jsfiddle.net/k68xatLw/1/)* - that was the problem. If it is still not working, you have some other, unrelated issues on your page.

Comment: Scott, No it didn't work on my site, but thanks for the info.

Comment: I understand and what I'm saying is that you must have some other issue because the fix that we are all telling you about is the correct fix and I've provided a link above for you to look at that shows that the code does work when the typo is fixed. This means that something else is now the new problem. You should open your "Developer Tools" in your browser, by hitting F12, and click on the "Console" tab to see if any errors are being reported.

Comment: Thank you Scott.

Comment: I will have to see what the issue is because it is not working at all on my site. Thank you all for the insight!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, this class is wrong?

```
.copiedCountLabel
```

Try to use class .copiesCountLabel as in your html code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.availableLabel.copiesCountLabel').text("Available in Region");
});
```

Comment: If it's just a simple typo, we generally just post a comment to that effect as that is a reason for closing a question.

Comment: As @ScottMarcus mentioned, your answer should be posted as a comment rather than an answer, and the post should be closed.

Comment: Well even with fixing the typo I am getting a Violation "Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 40ms"

Comment: @McNile83 That sounds like a warning from the developer tools, not a JavaScript error.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your selector.
You want to get *copiesCountLabel*, but trying to get *copie**d**CountLabel*.

Also think about using the *id* attribute for such unique classes.

Comment: If it's just a simple typo, we generally just post a comment to that effect as that is a reason for closing a question. I realize that you don't have enough rep. yet to comment, but thought you should know.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to select the label with both the classes need to write the selectors together without spaces in between.

In your case it is `.availableLabel.copiesCountLabel` the classes of label.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.availableLabel.copiesCountLabel').text("Available in Region ");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="availableDiv0" class="availableDiv copiesCountSection"><span class="availableLabel copiesCountLabel">Copies: </span><span style="display:inline-block;" name="smallSearchingGif" id="copiesCountNumber1040573" class="availableNumber copiesCountNumber">2</span></span>
```

One suggestion would be in case if this is the only element which needs to be change then better to use `id` instead of `class`

Comment: If it's just a simple typo, we generally just post a comment to that effect as that is a reason for closing a question.  Also, answers (when they are appropriate) should be accompanied by an explanation of the problem and the solution. Lastly, if your answer is the same as others that are already given, then you really shouldn't add it.

Comment: And surely you can provide a simple explanation rather than make people guess or code diff what is different. Code only answers aren't very helpful without an explanation

Comment: What do spaces have to do with OP's simple typo problem? No spaces in selector in the question and there is no need to invent problems that don't exist

Comment: The OP didn't include any spaces between the class names in the first place.